how to Validate dynamic Form fields with vee-validate v4 vue3?
I am trying to validate dynamic field like this, because the component is gonna be large to share, let me show you part of it, and the one that causes the bug,
<template>
 <Form  v-slot="{ errors, values }" @submit="onSubmit">
<div>
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <Field as="input" type="text" name='title' id="title" rules="required" placeholder="Title ..." />
  <ErrorMessage class="err" name="title" />
</div>


<div  v-for="ing, index in values.ingredients" :key="index">
  <div>
   <label :for="`ingredient${index}`">ingredient</label>
    <Field as="input" type="text" :id="`ingredient${index}`" :name="`ingredients[${index}].name`"
                        :placeholder="`ingredient ${index} ...`" rules="required" />
      <ErrorMessage class="err" :name="`ingredients[${index}].name`" />
  </div>
  <div >
  <label :for="`amount${index}`">ingredient</label>
     <Field as="input" type="text" :id="`amount${index}`" :name="`ingredients[${index}].amount`"                                                                :placeholder="`ingredient ${index} ...`" rules="required" />
       <ErrorMessage class="err" :name="`ingredients[${index}].amount`" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" @click="removeIngredient(index, values)">
                    <Icon name="mi:remove" />
  </button>
 </div>
  <button type="button" @click="addIngredient(values)">
                <Icon name="mi:add" />
  </button>
       
</Form>
</template>
<script>
import { reactive, ref, onMounted, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { configure, ErrorMessage, Form, Field, defineRule } from 'vee-validate';
import { integer, required, image, size, email } from '@vee-validate/rules';
export default defineComponent({
    name: "RecipeForm",
    setup() {
        const addIngredient = (values) => {
             values.ingredient = (values.ingredient || []).concat([{}]);
        };

        const removeIngredient = (index, values) => {
            values.ingredients = values.ingredients.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
        };
         onMounted(() => {

            initFlowbite();
            configure({
                validateOnInput: true,
            });
            defineRule("required", required)
            defineRule("email", email)
            defineRule("size", size)
            defineRule("integer", integer)
            defineRule("image", image)
        })

        const onSubmit = async (value) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(value, null, 2))
        }


        return {
            onSubmit,
            handleAddtional,
            handleFileChange,
            addIngredient,
        }
    },
    components: {
        Form,
        Field,
        ErrorMessage,
    }
});

</script>


I try to add it the form with the button add but says
Set operation on key "ingredients" failed: target is readonly
the error is on the addIngredient() ig
i try to search it it says props are readonly and i can't not get the value of ingredients and create field either. may be because i am new to vue or may be there is a concept that i miss to solve this.
any help is appreciated, any way i can achieve dynamic form validation.
thank you very much!
